# ansible playbook hosts, is there a way to filter by variable

Tags: ansible

I'm new to ansible so bear with me, if my question is a bit basic.

I have 10 WordPress sites with different themes, all of them are listed in the hosts file under 'production' group:

```
[production]

black.com

red.com

blue.com
```

Each site require different variables:

```
theme_name: black
```

Is there anyway that I can run a playbook on 'production' host group , using variable?

Answer (score 3):

You can not easily* filter by variables. But you could add your hosts to additional groups like so:

```
[production]
black.com
red.com
blue.com

[black]
black.com

[red]
red.com

[blue]
blue.com
```

Now for the theme name you an create group-vars files. For example, for the red group you create the file `group_vars/red` with the content:

```
theme_name: red
```

Now you can run your playbook with the `black`, `red` and `blue` groups.

<sup>* I guess there is a way, by running filters on the `hostvars` dict and reduce it to a list of hostnames matching your criteria. But this seems to be overhead and against best practice. If you want to target a specific set of hosts you should have a group for them in the inventory.</sup>

Comment: @boazbarkan, you'd better to vote it than say thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure your question is absolutely clear, but another possible answer to your questions might be:

You can assign variables directly to hosts or groups in the inventory, there is a good introduction as to how you can do this [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html).

Example lifted from the page, variables defined after the host entry:

```
[atlanta]
host1 http_port=80 maxRequestsPerChild=808
host2 http_port=303 maxRequestsPerChild=909
```

This should work fine for small amounts of hosts, although there are better approaches when working at scale.

hth.